# How to use storage data and pass it to provider method

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm looking for the way to save  (NgModel) value and pass it to another page (provider) and use it inside the method. I can pass the data but have no idea how to pas it to the function in provider.

**Ion item + button:**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="domain" placeholder="Your domain" clearInput></ion-input>
</ion-item>
  <button ion-button block outline color="light (click)="getData()">Zaloguj</button>
```

**Set function:**

```
  setData() {
    this.storage.set('domain', this.domain);
    console.log(this.domain);
```

**Get function:**

```
      getData() {
        this.storage.get('domain').then((domain) => {
          console.log(domain);
        });
```

**Function in which i want to use domain value:**

```
  getUsers() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(domain +'/users').subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

But it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not pass the `domain`value as an argument to `getUsers()`?

Comment: @Sébastien i tried, but then i got error in another page.

`getUsers() {
    this.restapiService.getUsers(domain)
    .then(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log(this.users);
    });
  }`

Second line (domain) - Cannot find name. Any idea ?

Comment: Where is declared your domain variable? The one you are using in your getUsers method

Comment: @JordyGarcía it's declared in login.ts (file for ng-model). I pass it to provider, and then try to use it in home.ts